# How to determine what is included with jQuery Tools minified file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I've inherited a project that includes a minified version of [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html). The jQuery Tools site allows you to download a customized build with various user-selected script options.

How can I determine which options were included with the minified version so I can get the same options when I download the update?

I've looked at the file and there is no information in the header describing what's included. How is it ever possible to upgrade without knowing the original build components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Tools, but I just thought of running this in the address bar of the page containing Tools (tested in Chrome):

```
javascript:alert(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(jQuery.tools)));
```

This will list all the methods in the $.tools object (plus 'version'), but I don't know if this is really a complete list of included parts or not.

If this doesn't list them properly, your only option is likely trial and error.

Comment: I get: ["version","tooltip","overlay","__eht"] Hmm...any idea what "__eht" is?

Comment: Not a clue. I don't see it anywhere. Searching the minified file might give some hint to what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for

If you are using Firebug or similar JavaScript debugger you can easily test which tools are included and what are their versions by running the following command from the console:

console.dir($.tools);

from
http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/basics.html#include